# something wrong with DensityPlot of planewave

Tags: plotting

I am try to show a simple plane wave by DensityPlot the real part of $e^{ikr}$, $k=(k_x,k_y)$, $r=(x,y)$.

```
DensityPlot[Cos[(3 x + 4 y)], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Frame -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

Here $k=(3,4)$, It is supposed to be a clear stripe, however there is something wrong with the image as I show below.

[image].

Then I tried to change $k$ to $k=(1,1)$, this time it looks correct.

```
DensityPlot[Cos[(x + y)], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Frame -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image]

I am wondering why it happens and how to change the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does specifying `PlotPoints` work?

```
DensityPlot[Cos[(3 x + 4 y)], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Frame -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

Comment: It does! Thank you.

Comment: you are welcome